# Cannot trigger Domain-wide installation for a test G Suite marketplace project

Tags: google-api

I have a test application, created through the Google Developers Console. The application use the G Suite Marketplace SDK and G Suite Marketplace API. The application also uses domain-wide installation.

Usually, to test this app, I go to APIs & Services > G Suite Marketplace SDK and click the "Integrate with Google" button.

[image: G Suite Marketplace SDK]

Once I click the "Integrate with Google" button, I get to see the following screen:

[image: DWD installation screen]

Usually, when I click the "Continue" button, the app is installed and I can successfully integrate with the application. However, this **stopped** working for one particular test G Suite domain.

Thing is: I see no error. After clicking the "Continue" button, simply nothing happens.

Any clue how I can troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I updated the billing information, the integration started working again.

And then, after some time, it stopped working again, because the "Integrate with Google" button was completely removed. That was due to an update in UI. Also, the only way to test integrations now is to "publish" an application with private visibility.

Also see: ["Test installation flow"/"Integrate with Google" button missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829761/test-installation-flow-integrate-with-google-button-missing)